# Get the file name without extension and concatenate pattern from file name

Tags: linux, shell-script

I have these excel files in a user directory:

```
430_XFRtoDML.xlsx
431_XFRtoDML.xlsx
440_XFRtoDML.xlsx
450_XFRtoDML.xlsx
451_XFRtoDML.xlsx
465_XFRtoDML.xlsx
500_XFRtoDML.xlsx
```

Path: `/home/user`

I want to write a script to create a text file `bit_list.txt`
mentined below. It should remove the xlsx extension followed by `:5.`  and first 3 number from that file. e.g. `430_XFRtoDML:5. 430`

```
filenames=`ls *.xlsx`
for eachfile in $filenames
do
   echo $eachfile
done
```

Expected output:

```
$ cat bit_list.txt
430_XFRtoDML:5. 430
431_XFRtoDML:5. 431
440_XFRtoDML:5. 440
450_XFRtoDML:5. 450
451_XFRtoDML:5. 451
465_XFRtoDML:5. 465
500_XFRtoDML:5. 500
```

Comment: Do not parse `ls` --> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead

Comment: Something like (untested) `rename 's/(...)(_XFRto_DML)\.xlsx/$1$2:5. $1/ *`

Comment: OP does not want to rename?

Comment: Oh, right. Then that substitution has to be put into a perl script, something like (still untested) `perl -le 'BEGIN { opendir $a, "." } while (readdir $a) { s/(...)(_XFRto_DML)\.xlsx/$1$2:5. $1/; print; }'`

Answer (score 2):

1. [Don't parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead), rather use `*.xlsx` directly in the for-loop.
2. Make use of the shells [parameter substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) possibilities.
3. [Use `printf` instead of `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).

```bsh
for file in *.xlsx; do
    name="${file%.*}"
    num="${file:0:3}"
    printf '%s:5. %d\n' "$name" "$num"
done > bit_list.txt
```